# Close one Frame (not the whole application) using AWT

Tags: java, user-interface, awt

On click, How to close only one `Frame` not both or whole application? 
(I have also tried with AWT Event dispatch, EDT)

```
package test;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class Test11 extends Frame implements MouseListener
{
  public static Frame gp;  
  public Test11()
  { 
    try {            
       this.setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
       Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
       this.setBounds(screen.width-400,33,400, 400);   
       this.setBackground(Color.red);
       this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
       {
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) 
         {
           System.exit(0);
         }
       });       
       this.addMouseListener(this);       
       this.setVisible(true);
    } finally {
    }    
  }

  /* How do i do AWT Event Dispatch (EDT): to cloase AWT window? */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, InvocationTargetException 
  {
    /* EDT: AWT Event Dispatch
    EventQueue eventQueue = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue();
    eventQueue.push(new MyEventQueue()); */

    /* Simple close */
    EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() 
    {
      public void run() 
      {
        System.out.println("Run: Window 1");
        gp = new Test11();
        gp.setVisible(true);      
        //gp.setVisible(false);
      }
    });

    /* Simple close */
    EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() 
    {
      public void run() 
      {
        System.out.println("Run: Window 2");
        new Test11().setVisible(true);
      }
    });

  }

  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) 
  {
    System.out.println("Clicked: out of Window1 or Window2, close only any one not whole application");
    System.exit(0);
  }

  @Override
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
  }

  /* EDT: Extended class
  private static class MyEventQueue extends EventQueue 
  {
    public void postEvent(AWTEvent theEvent) 
    {
      System.out.println("Event Posted"); 
      super.postEvent(theEvent);
    }
  }
  */  
}
```

**Follow up:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test11 extends Frame 
{
    public static Frame window1;
    public static Frame window2;

    public Test11(String title) {
        super(title);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setBackground(Color.red);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                System.out.println(
                    getTitle() +
                    " says Bye-Bye!  " +
                    new java.util.Date());
                dispose();
            }
        });
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* AFAIU starting the GUI on the EDT only applies to Swing.*/
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Run: Window 1");
                window1 = new Test11("Window 1");
                window1.setVisible(true);

                System.out.println("Run: Window 2");
                window2 = new Test11("Window 2"); 
                window2.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        /* Remotely: i need to close thi window, not manually */
        window2.setVisible(false);
        /* failed then try */
        window2.dispose();

        /* Now: I should have only Window1, but that i am not able to make yet */
    }
}
```

Comment: please could you be little bit concrete about your reason(s), because I miss that in your question

Comment: BTW - meant to ask this before, but forgot.  For what exact reason is this app. using AWT components in this millennium?  You will get better help on Swing - if only for the fact that developers might have used it in the last decade and can remember it.  ;)

Comment: FYI, This is for a Media player, where full HD film is getting played on the Window2 and Window1 is button controller's.

Comment: *"FYI, This is for a Media player.."*  Was that supposed to be an answer to my question?  If the library you are using does not support Swing, get a better one.  Heck, even the *JMF* had built in Swing support.  Either that or target 1.7+, where mixing Swing and AWT has again become 'the cool thing'.

Comment: Thank you Guru Andrew Thompson it works. I do not have to use AWT i was confused because sometimes in Swing when i play films like 60 frames per second, i see some grey background show up, that is why i was using AWT but its not must i will switch to Swing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test11 extends Frame {

    public Test11(String title) {
        super(title);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setBackground(Color.red);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                System.out.println(
                    getTitle() +
                    " says Bye-Bye!  " +
                    new java.util.Date());
                dispose();
            }
        });
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* AFAIU starting the GUI on the EDT only applies to Swing.*/
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Run: Window 1");
                (new Test11("Window 1")).setVisible(true);
                System.out.println("Run: Window 2");
                (new Test11("Window 2")).setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### Typical Output

```
Run: Window 1
Run: Window 2
Window 1 says Bye-Bye!  Mon Nov 14 10:20:25 EST 2011
Window 2 says Bye-Bye!  Mon Nov 14 10:20:35 EST 2011
Press any key to continue . . .
```

### Update 1

This code closes "Window 2" programatically.  The problem with your version was 'timing', caused by the call to invoke **later** (what do you think that means?).  It can be fixed in one of two relatively easy ways.

1. The kludge.  Add a Swing `Timer`/`ActionListener` set to go off 2 seconds after the main runs.  For that route, take out the 'comment part' of all the commented code lines in the main.
2. The better solution.  Remove the call to `EventQueue.invokeLater()`, which is irrelevant to AWT components.

Here is the altered code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
// since the OP has not taken the time to explain 'why AWT',
// I choose to make life easy by using a Swing class.
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test11 extends Frame
{
    public static Frame window1;
    public static Frame window2;

    public Test11(String title) {
        super(title);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setBackground(Color.red);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                System.out.println(
                    getTitle() +
                    " says Bye-Bye!  " +
                    new java.util.Date());
                dispose();
            }
        });
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // AFAIU starting the GUI on the EDT only applies to Swing.
        //EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        //    public void run() {
                System.out.println("Run: Window 1");
                window1 = new Test11("Window 1");
                window1.setVisible(true);

                System.out.println("Run: Window 2");
                window2 = new Test11("Window 2");
                window2.setVisible(true);
        //    }
        //});

        //ActionListener closeWindow = new ActionListener(){
        //  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                System.out.println(
                    window2.getTitle() +
                    " says Bye-Bye!  " +
                    new java.util.Date());
                /* failed then try */
                window2.dispose();
        //  }
        //};
        //Timer timer = new Timer(2000,closeWindow);
        //timer.setRepeats(false);
        //timer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: @mKorbel (chuckle)  I updated *your* link from 6->7 (nervous habit) and checked the link was valid without realizing it pointed to a Swing specific method.  It was only when I was working with the source, with the intent of showing how easy it was to use `setDefaultCloseOperation(int)` that my **compiler** helpfully warned me WTE "Making up methods - stop that!".  ;)  JavaDocs are great, but compilers are better.  :)

Comment: 1) in AWT times I built towers from sand 2) I don't believe in Java7 in the present form, new o.w.n.e.r == everything d.i.e.d, only 7 is there

Comment: Re 2) Oh don't get me wrong!  I would not have J7 on this machine, yet.  It didn't work at all with my DukeBox so I reverted to 6 till a more stable JRE came along.  The JavaDocs OTOH, are a different matter.  Just want to see 1.4.2 dropped out of Google links, and getting lots of links to the 7 docs might (?) produce that result.

Comment: <only jokes> maybe I wrong but you are out off any chances, if I remember correctly this engines has Alphabetical ordering, then 1.4.2, 1.5, sometimes 6 (-: on the 5mio, 758T, 856 possition on Google :-) and I never saw there something like as Java7, what's Java7, no Google, sorry no way, --> please don't stop with thinking in Java7, maybe once day, but not tomorrow :-) </only jokes>

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: See my edit please (follow up section). I cant close now the Window2 in that way yet (pro-grammatically not, but yes with mouse click it close).

Answer (score 3):

Look at [setDefaultCloseOperation()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29): `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` is the proper attribute for that behavior, these methods are valid for Swing,

EDIT:

if you want to reuse this/these container(s), then

```
this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
        this.setVisible(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have two Frame/Window (AWT) open. Once i want to close one, i want only that get closed. But not the whole application like System.exit(0) is now doing.

Comment: @Google and if you want to listening somthing about these changes then check http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html and http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html , both are accesible for AWT and Swing Container too

Comment: I see both in the http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html, then for JFrame by default, or I miss_something another in your comment :-)

Comment: The OP is using pure AWT, so there is no `setDefaultCloseOperation(int)` available.

Comment: The problem with `this.setVisible(false);` is that it does not dispose of the thread for that frame.  After they are all closed, the JRE will still be running.  If they are instead **disposed,** as in my example, the JRE will exit after the last frame disappears.

Comment: @mKorbel: thank you. I was using Andrew Thompson example it worked but i need to close the window using mouse. Which is not in my case. But the goal is, i need to close the window2 using window1 button.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method for this is to use:

```
dispose();
```

This simply closes the window associated with the file if placed inside an onClickListener. This doesn't terminate the whole program.

Answer (score 0):

in Design Mode you have to go to the properities of the jframe with the right clic and select:
DISPOSE in defaultcloseoperation line (normally is the first line).

all this operation are easier in design.
I'm talking for netbeans but I hope it's similar in another ide.